# is there a faster way to remove all keyup eventListeners on a document

Tags: javascript, dom, events

i have a function that removes and adds keyup listeners to a webpage

```js
function addFunc1() {
  document.addEventListener('keyup', func1);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func2);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func3);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func4);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func5);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func6);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func7);
}
function addFunc2() {
  document.addEventListener("keyup", func2);
  document.removeEventListener('keyup', func1);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func3);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func4);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func5);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func6);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func7);
}
function addFunc3() {
  document.addEventListener("keyup", func3);
  document.removeEventListener('keyup', func1);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func2);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func4);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func5);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func6);
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", func7);
}
...etc
```

but im wondering if there is a faster way to remove them? because i think its very slow if i remove them one by one

i tried searching but only found solutions with `cloneNode` like this to remove all event handlers in an element

```js
var clone = element.cloneNode(true);
```

but i dont think this will work for what i want

this question has probably been asked before but i just couldn't find it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the functions into an array

```
const fns = [func1, func2, ...];
```

Then instead of

```
function addFunc1() {
```

```
function addFunc2() {
```

do

```
function addFunc(indexToAdd) {
  for (const fn of fns) {
    document.removeEventListener("keyup", fn);
  }
  document.addEventListener("keyup", fns[indexToAdd]);
}
addFunc(0);
// or
// addFunc(1);
```

Another approach would be to have only a single function, active all the time, and you reassign the active index:

```
let activeIndex = 0; // for example: have keyups run the first function
document.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  fns[activeIndex]();
});
```

Then to, for example, switch to `func3` instead of `func1`, just do

```
activeIndex = 2;
```